# Select root element of a transclusion in a component with multiple transclusions

Tags: angular

I am writing components to help with implementing Semantic-UI elements. My template for the 'card' element contains several `<ng-content>` elements used for transclusion of specific sections of the card. Due to the specifics of Semantic-UI's CSS, I wish to apply class names to the root elements of some of the transclusions. I have tried using a wrapper element with the class assigned but that causes some bugs in the child elements due to incorrect nesting for the CSS rules.

The component template at this time:

```
<div class="image" *ngIf="image">
  <img src="{{image}}">
</div>
<div class="content">
  <ng-content select="[card-title]"></ng-content>
  <div class="meta">
    <ng-content select="[card-subtitle]"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <ng-content select="[card-content]"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="extra content">
  <ng-content select="[card-extra]"></ng-content>
</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Ideally, I want something closer to this but understand that you cannot just assign class names to `<ng-content>`:

```
<div class="image" *ngIf="image">
  <img src="{{image}}">
</div>
<div class="content">
  <ng-content select="[card-title]"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="[card-subtitle]" class="meta"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="[card-content]" class="description"></ng-content>
</div>
<ng-content select="[card-extra]" class="extra content"></ng-content>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Is there any way I can select the root element of what replaces `[card-subtitle]` so that I can then add the class "meta" to it? I've seen a couple of answers but they assume you only have a single `<ng-content>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference of each *content child* with the `@ContentChild` decorator and then use something like `Renderer2` to add a class to each corresponding `nativeElement`. Notice however, that you have to pass a component or directive to the `@ContentChild` decorator, so this will only work if `card-title`, for example, is a selector for let's say  `SemanticUiCardTitleDirective` and also you need a reference to the native element, so you have to set the read property to `ElementRef`.

So, inside your component:

```
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { SemanticUiCardTitleDirective, //...etc } from 'path/to/directives';

@Component({..})
export class SomeComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(SemanticUiCardTitleDirective, { read: ElementRef })
  cardTitle: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.cardTitle.nativeElement, 'some-class');
  }
}
```